# how to calculate the fields where null cells in the cross table in spotfire report

Tags: spotfire

I got few null cells when we prepare the Spotfire cross table report, the dataset doen't have any blanks but the report picks up as null value and its not included for calculating the cells. have attached the sample screen shot for your reference. Please help me to resolve this issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMREs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Answer could be more detailed if you included axis expression for cell values.

Assuming you have columns called [YTD Plan] and [YTD Actual], then I am assuming your axis expression looks similar to:

```
Sum([YTD Plan]) as [YTD Plan], 
Sum([YTD Actual]) as [YTD Actual], 
Sum([YTD Plan]) - Sum([YTD Actual]) as [YTD Plan vs. YTD Actual]
```

Your issue is that minus returns a null value when applied to null. By performing null value replacement you can compensate for this. Try using something like:

```
Sum([YTD Plan]) as [YTD Plan],
Sum([YTD Actual]) as [YTD Actual],
Sum([YTD Plan]) - SN(Sum([YTD Actual]), 0) as [YTD Plan vs. YTD Actual]
```

Notice the SN function applied within the third measure, which will replace null values with 0.

Comment: Fantastic.. its working exactly what I expect in the report.             
Sum(If([Qtr]="Plan",[Total  Value $]))/12*integer(${RPeriod}) as [YTD Plan],
Sum(If([Qtr]<>"Plan",[Total  Value $])) as [YTD Actual],
SN(Sum(If([Qtr]="Plan",[Total  Value $])),0)/12*Integer(${RPeriod}) - SN(Sum(If([Qtr]<>"Plan",[Total  Value $])),0) as [YTD Plan vs. YTD Actual] Thanks for your support my friend

Comment: Great! Could you please mark response as correct answer? @ManikandanRaghavan